# Managing user from joomla front end

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Is there any free or commercial extensions for joomla to manage users from front end ?

I'm using joomla 2.5

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amilaishere Take a look at DM Frontend User Manager http://www.dmjoomlaextensions.com/ its commercial one. It has good AJAX feature & many more. It kicks ass when it comes to customize this extension. I have developed such component for one of our project. So if you want I'll share it with you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I bought that plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.Its a commercial extention

http://www.joomlarra.com/joomla-2.5-user-export-import-documentation/joomla-25-user-profile-fields.html

check these too
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Comment: Thank You very much. I'll check

Comment: Well those plugins aren't suit for my needs. I simply need to add joomla back-end user management feature to joomla front end. then site managers can easily manage users without log in to joomla back end.